# Binding formatted strings from XML file with data binding not working correctly

Tags: android, xml, string, data-binding, formatted

When developing with data binding to bind formatted strings directly in the XML file, the `@{@string/stringName}` does not work as normal attribute `@string/stringName` without data binding, and neither does `@{String.format(@string/stringName)}`.

I would like to know how to use data binding to use formatted strings such as `<string name="my_string"> <font face="font_name" color="hex_color"> my text here with %s </font> </string>` along with data binding, because `@{@string/my_string("My name")}` doesn't work correctly. I mean, it does appear with the "My name" inserted on the string, but no formatted attribute like font or color.

If I don't use data binding and just `@string/myName` the formatted attributes font and color work propperly, but I don't get the input for `%s`.

Thank you all.

Comment: Have u got any solution of this?

Comment: Yes, for the span tags to work, you must call the Span.fromHtml() inside the XML with databinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still looking for this, you just have to call Span.fromHtml() in the XML file. Also don't forget to import it.

```
@{Span.fromHtml(@string/stringName("Julio"))}
```